# Test for a logistic distribution in R

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, distributions, logistic-distribution

I have a set of data and I'd like to know whether this data set has a logistic distribution. When I made a histogram of my data set it seems to have a logistic distribution, but to be sure I'd like to test for a logistic distribution in R. 
[image]
So my question is: **Is there a way to test your data for a logistic distribution in R and how do you do this?**

Additional information: The data set consists of 8544 items. The data are horizontal distances in km between 2 geographical points. I need the data to construct a dispersal kernel for elephants. I could construct this dispersal kernel more easily if the data had a normal or a logistic distribution. I already used a Kolmogorov Smirnov test to test for a normal distribution (p<0.05), but the result was significant, so the data are not normally distributed.

Comment: A number of distributions will fit this bill. Two other candidates that come to mind are Weibull and Poisson distributions. Googling "how to fit a distribution in r" spits out this pdf: http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Ricci-distributions-en.pdf

Comment: User, could you please say some more about what this kernel means and how you intend to use it? One of my concerns (among many) is that if you use a fitted curve to these data for the *radial* function of the kernel, then (because it is in two dimensions, not one) the actual distribution created by applying this kernel will (strongly) differ from the observed distribution!

Comment: The data you have shown us CANNOT be logistic, the logistic distribution is symmetric, so at most your data could be half-logistic!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure what makes you think this may be the [logistic distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_distribution), it doesn't really look like that to me.  I'm not sure how good I am at just guessing the distribution from a picture, but I might start by playing with something like the [exponential distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution) or the [$\chi^2$ distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution), given your histogram.

There are a couple of possibilities for assessing whether your data come from a given distribution.  My typical preferred strategy is to assess this graphically using a [qq-plot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-Q_plot).  In R, the [car package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/car//index.html) has a really nice augmented version, [?qq.plot](http://hosho.ees.hokudai.ac.jp/~kubo/Rdoc/library/car/html/qq.plot.html), that you can use with different distributions besides just the normal, and which will plot a confidence band for you as well.  I've never tried it with the logistic, but it may be possible.  For a *statistical test*, the [Kolmogorov-Smirnov test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test) can be used for more than just the normal distribution as well; in R the function would be [?ks.test](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/ks.test.html), although again, I've never used it to check the logistic distribution.  In both cases, R's root name for the logistic distribution is "[logis](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/Logistic.html)".

Something else you might want to look into is the package [fitdistrplus](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fitdistrplus/index.html), which has a lot of nice options for examining distributions.  Of course, its raison d'etre is determining parameters by maximum likelihood, but it goes well beyond that.  The [vignette](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fitdistrplus/vignettes/intro2fitdistrplus.pdf) offers a nice tutorial for the package and exploring distributions more generally.